# How I can move controls such as TabControl or MenuStrip ans SubMenuStrip from left to right by using code in vc#?

Tags: c#, right-to-left

I have used the following code and it works fine with the common controls such as Buttons, TextBox, label and ComboBox :

```
// For Change any button position from left to right

    public static void ChangeButtonPosition(Form f,Button b)

    {
                Point p = new Point();
                p.X = f.Size.Width - (b.Size.Width + b.Location.X + 10);
                p.Y = b.Location.Y;
                b.Location = p; 
            }
```

But when I applied such code to change the position of controls such as TabControl or MenuStrip ans SubMenuStrip nothing happen and the control keeps in it's position.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the tabcontrol in the same way as a button using something like this:

```
Point p = new Point();
p.X =  tabControl1.Location.X + 10;
p.Y = tabControl1.Location.Y + 10;
tabControl1.Location = p;
```

But the other controls aren't rendered controls on the form so they don't have a Location property that you can set.

Comment: But how do u think the property RightToLeft works for the  MenuStrip and SubMenuStrip?

Comment: The RightToLeft property is used when localising your software into languages that read from right to left. Arabic, for example. 

The RightToLeft property will make that control read from right to left.

Comment: Thank u for your help :) Exactly I want localize an app without using RightToLeft property I have did that but I got problem in  localize the MenuStrip and SubMenuStrip. :(